# MySQL Select another row if one doesn't exist

Tags: mysql

I need to select a row from the table with the specific id, but if the row doesn't exist I need to select the first row. is it possible to do it in a single query?

example:
I have a table with an id and text fields. and I have 3 rows in the table

```
id    txt
----------------
1     text1
2     text2
3     text3
```

I need to select the first row if say `SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE id = 4` doesn't exist Else select the row with id 4.

Comment: it might be possible but that depends on several aspects... please show some table structure, SQL query... what have you tried ? how do you identify the "first row" ?

Comment: From a relational standpoint, there's no such thing as a first row because tables have no natural order. What's your ordering to determine the first row?

Comment: I mean the row with the lowest id.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM 
   (SELECT * FROM your_table
      WHERE id = your_id
      LIMIT 1
    UNION
    SELECT * FROM your_table
      LIMIT 1) a
LIMIT 1
```

The idea is to take first desired row and appending to this very first row, finally taking first one. If desired row does not exists, first one will be selected...

Comment: Is this guaranteed to return the specific one if its there?  I wouldn't expect the `union` statement to preserve the order of returned rows, such that the "top" row could still be returned in this query even if the specific one exists.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * FROM (
   SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE [..your criteria...] LIMIT 1
   UNION
   SELECT * FROM table1 LIMIT 1    
) LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here there is another way that may be considered

```
SELECT * FROM table1  
WHERE [criteria 1] AND [criteria 2]  

UNION 

SELECT * FROM table1  
WHERE [criteria 1] AND NOT EXISTS 
(
   SELECT * FROM table1  
   WHERE [criteria 1] AND [criteria 2]    
)

LIMIT 1;
```