# [MySQL]: Get product row - if doesn't exist by brand & product_code - get only by brand where product_code is empty

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table of shop_product_videos:

id | brand | product_code | link

Everytime I load my page it gets the video for the specific product using this MySQL query:

```
SELECT link FROM shop_product_videos WHERE brand='$brand' AND product_code='$product_code' LIMIT 1
```

and displays it.

Example:

```
$brand = "Samsung"; 
$product_code = 111;

43 | Samsung | 111 | youtube.be/111222333
```

So if my page loads a product named "Samsung" and it has a "111" as a "product_code", it will display the video link from the row in the DB.

I want to update my function to situations when there is only a brand name but there is no product_code in my table (empty/null), and I want to display a "general video" for that product (and all items that have "Samsung" as a brand).

Wanted result example:

```
$brand = "Samsung"; 
$product_code = 777; 

43 | Samsung | 111 | youtube.be/111222333
44 | Samsung |  | youtube.be/444555666
```

Running a query I will get the second row (id 44) with the video since it didn't find a total match with the 777 `product_code`

Comment: what you had tried??

Comment: I think this what you want `SELECT link FROM shop_product_videos WHERE brand='$brand' AND (product_code is null or product_code='$product_code') LIMIT 1`

Comment: @SagarGangwal

Things like: 
`SELECT * FROM ( SELECT * FROM shop_product_videos WHERE brand='Samsung' AND product_code='111' LIMIT 1 UNION SELECT * FROM shop_product_videos WHERE brand='Samsung' AND product_code='' LIMIT 1 ) LIMIT 1`



that im not sure of

( Following this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8076176/mysql-select-another-row-if-one-doesnt-exist )

Comment: @RickSanchez What do you mean by general video? As shown by you if product ID is blank or null still there is link for video is possible?

Comment: @SagarGangwal 
It doesn't find product_code 777 in the table - so it goes and search for the row there the brand match and product_code is empty. so it still results a video link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simple use `OR`

```
SELECT link FROM shop_product_videos 
WHERE brand='$brand' 
AND (product_code is null or product_code='$product_code') 
LIMIT 1
```

**Update 1 :**

```
SELECT link FROM shop_product_videos 
WHERE brand='$brand' 
AND ( product_code='$product_code' or product_code='' or product_code is null) LIMIT 1
```

Comment: @downvoter can you please explain . so that i can correct my mistake .

Comment: It gets the product if it has an existing product_code in the db. but it a situation where there is no product_code matching - it returns an empty restult.

Comment: what is your column `default value` when it's `empty` @RickSanchez

Comment: Try this one `SELECT link FROM shop_product_videos 
WHERE brand='$brand' 
AND ( product_code='$product_code'  or product_code=''  or product_code is null) 
LIMIT 1` @RickSanchez

Comment: it's just empty `""`.

Comment: Glad it help you :)  @RickSanchez

Answer (score 0):

You can do the first query, verify the result to see if is empty (no result with that product id found). In the case is empty, make another query to take all the results you want:

If you want all rows:

`SELECT link FROM shop_product_videos WHERE brand='$brand' OR product_code is NULL`

If you want one of each:

```
(SELECT link FROM shop_product_videos WHERE brand='$brand' LIMIT 1) UNION (SELECT link FROM shop_product_videos WHERE product_code is NULL LIMIT 1)
```

Comment: As mentioned in the example - 

If returns a row by the 2 variables (brand and product_code) then it's fine. if doesn't where product_code doesn't exist - return the row where product_code is empty.

first query doesn't result this. Second result an error `#1221 - Incorrect usage of UNION and LIMIT`